# How to avoid using loop in order to optimize this array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code, where the loop goes over the clientsarray and it takes time if the array is big enough. Especially since I make 2 loops.

How can I optimize this?

```
var user_hash = obj.user_hash_id;
    var socketto_id_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < clientsarray.length; i++) {
        if (clientsarray[i].user_hash == obj.user_hash_id) {
            for (var j = 0; j < clientsarray[i].locations.length; j++) {
                socketto_id_array.push(clientsarray[i].locations[j].socket);
            }
        }
    }
```

clientsarray:

```
[ { room: 'ppyxVpUnGzwmBENcvDF10RTtuSWgaMf5CkZesHdAP2jJ19Q4b',
    user_hash: 'Go2JupqINq7',
    locations: [ [Object] ],
    fblisteners: [ [Reference] ],
    updated: 2020-03-03T14:13:06.288Z },
  { room: 'abJAV7F2gZpkP5tCX91KbcMu2YwhG6Esry8mvWxfnHUj3RaN0',
    user_hash: 'pBSrPEcZtFb',
    locations: [ [Object] ],
    fblisteners: [ [Reference] ],
    updated: 2020-03-03T14:13:07.579Z },
  { room: 'u89jTzSmxbWuEwCRGync1YUfsNQhtV6ZfXA3d04B8De5pHqvM',
    user_hash: 'xJBU1j2X0FY',
    locations: [ [Object] ],
    fblisteners: [ [Reference] ],
    updated: 2020-03-03T14:13:07.417Z },
  { room: 'gqtKR2uebFCZv6M0dQAS94phwGPgYr5HDJBUXfEWNmxq7an8s',
    user_hash: '9CL2D10wa7o',
    locations: [ [Object] ],
    fblisteners: [ [Reference] ],
```

Thank you

Comment: not enough data. Please provide clientsarray example

Comment: @demkovych hi, thank you. I have updated the question with example

Comment: Is it possible, that there's more than one same value for `user_hash` in data?

Comment: @Teemu no, each `user_hash` is unique

Comment: Then you could break the outer loop when the first match has been found and handled. Notice also, that you're caching `obj.user_hash_id` into a variable, but never using it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try using `Array.filter` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)). If each hash is unique, `Array.find` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) is the better choice, because it doesn't necessarily loops the complete Array.</strike> Coming to think of it, if `client_hash` is unique and you just need the `socket` from the `locations`-property, a simple `reduce` would suffice ([reduce @MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)). If `socket` is not a number, you should work something out for yourself.

```js
const user_hash = `pBSrPEcZtFb`;
const client_array = [ 
  { room: 'ppyxVpUnGzwmBENcvDF10RTtuSWgaMf5CkZesHdAP2jJ19Q4b',
    user_hash: 'Go2JupqINq7',
    locations: { socket: 23 } },
  { room: 'abJAV7F2gZpkP5tCX91KbcMu2YwhG6Esry8mvWxfnHUj3RaN0',
    user_hash: 'pBSrPEcZtFb',
    locations: { socket: 267 } },
  { room: 'u89jTzSmxbWuEwCRGync1YUfsNQhtV6ZfXA3d04B8De5pHqvM',
    user_hash: 'xJBU1j2X0FY',
    locations: { socket: 3 } },
  { room: 'gqtKR2uebFCZv6M0dQAS94phwGPgYr5HDJBUXfEWNmxq7an8s',
    user_hash: '9CL2D10wa7o',
    locations: { socket: 981 } } ];

// just retrieve the socket for user_hash
const just_socketto_id = client_array
  .reduce( (acc, val) => 
    val.user_hash == user_hash ? val.locations.socket : acc, -1);
    
if (just_socketto_id > -1) {
  console.log(`Found socket for ${user_hash}: ${just_socketto_id}`);
} else {
  console.log(`Socket for ${user_hash} not found`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me which part of the code shall I replace with it?

Comment: That's up to you, I simplified the client_array, because `locations: [ [Object] ],` is not workable. The `filter` delivers an `Array`, which can be mapped to what you need (still will be an `Array`), `find` delivers the found `Object`, from which you can pick a property

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{
    room: 'ppyxVpUnGzwmBENcvDF10RTtuSWgaMf5CkZesHdAP2jJ19Q4b',
    user_hash: 'Go2JupqINq7',
    locations: [{
      socket: 1
    }, {
      socket: 2
    }]
  },
  {
    room: 'abJAV7F2gZpkP5tCX91KbcMu2YwhG6Esry8mvWxfnHUj3RaN0',
    user_hash: 'pBSrPEcZtFb',
    locations: [{
      socket: 2
    }]
  }

]
const userHash = 'Go2JupqINq7';

const socketsList = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.user_hash === userHash) acc = [...acc, ...el.locations.map(loc => loc.socket)];

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(socketsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter will loop over your array and increase complexity,you can do something like that.

Instead of build an array, build a object, that way you can find the room by user hash just doing, you also avoid duplicates.

```
//creates a object
    var user_hash = obj.user_hash_id;
    var socketto_id_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < clientsarray.length; i++) {
        if (clientsarray[i].user_hash == obj.user_hash_id) {
                socketto_id_array[clientsarray[i].user_hash] = clientsarray[i].locations;
        }
    }

//Gets by userHash
socketto_id_array["user_hash_toFind"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a faster than O(n^2) solution exists, but you can achieve the same results with the following one liner.

```
socketto_id_array = clientsarray.filter(obj => obj.user_hash === userHash).flatMap(obj => (obj.locations.map(loc => loc.socket)));
```

The `filter()` is linear-time, and the `flatMap()` is linear-time and linear-space, but since there's another map occurring within this it makes this as perform-ant as what you already have, but with less code.